# PayPal REST API working in Sandbox, but not in live (using Node SDK)

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

we have a web app written in Node where we have a payment page that uses the PayPal REST API.

We have been testing the payment page using sandbox for a few weeks now without any errors and we went through the whole approval process to enable direct credit card payments on our account, but when we change the credentials and URL on our app to the ones from live, we get a Client Authentication error.

We have gone over this issue with integration experts over the phone (for hours) and opened a ticket with PayPal support and no one has been able to help us.

This is our debug ID:

Debug ID for sandbox: 7b06479ae1ef3 (successful payment)

Debug ID for live: 8843fb4d4cbcf (failed payment)

Exact same code, only thing that changes are our credentials and URL.

The few people we have talked to in PayPal point to it as a credentials issue, but we have created a new app in our dashboard and gotten new credentials only to get the same error.

What could be going on?

Is switching from sandbox to live not as simple as just switching the URL and Client/Secret?